# Web Devs, How do you manage your clients information?

Tags: user-management

I'm looking for some sort of web software that is secure, where a team of people can login and view/add/edit Clients, with the following normal meta data:

- Client Name
- Domain
- FTP User/Pass
- MySQL User/Pass
- CMS User/Pass

Anyone have any recommendations, don't really want to create a php script myself?

The problem at the moment is: We currently administrate a .DOC with all the information in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at https://lastpass.com or http://www.passpack.com/ which allows you to share credentials with people.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any specific software that could help you, however, I have used Basecamp before which is a payed cloud based service.

http://basecamphq.com/

They also offer something called 'highrise' which could better suit your needs:

http://highrisehq.com/